# RuntimeError importing tensorflow that goes away the second time it is imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

tensorflow - 1.9.0
numpy - 1.13.1

i try to install tensorflow and it throws me RuntimeError :

```
RuntimeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb


RuntimeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xb
```

though it gives an error while importing, something did happen because running tf.contrib.layers does not give tf not found but another error:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-28c9425cf301> in <module>()
----> 1 tf.contrib.layers

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.pyc in __getattr__(self, item)
     51 
     52   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 53     module = self._load()
     54     return getattr(module, item)
     55 

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.pyc in _load(self)
     40   def _load(self):
     41     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 42     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     43     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     44 

/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.pyc in import_module(name, package)
     35             level += 1
     36         name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
---> 37     __import__(name)
     38     return sys.modules[name]

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py in <module>()
     37 from tensorflow.contrib import deprecated
     38 from tensorflow.contrib import distribute
---> 39 from tensorflow.contrib import distributions
     40 from tensorflow.contrib import estimator
     41 from tensorflow.contrib import factorization

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/__init__.py in <module>()
     38 from tensorflow.contrib.distributions.python.ops.distribution_util import softplus_inverse
     39 from tensorflow.contrib.distributions.python.ops.distribution_util import tridiag
---> 40 from tensorflow.contrib.distributions.python.ops.estimator import *
     41 from tensorflow.contrib.distributions.python.ops.geometric import *
     42 from tensorflow.contrib.distributions.python.ops.half_normal import *

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/estimator.py in <module>()
     19 from __future__ import print_function
     20 
---> 21 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.head import _compute_weighted_loss
     22 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.head import _RegressionHead
     23 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/__init__.py in <module>()
     93 
     94 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 95 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
     96 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     97 

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
     29 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/__init__.py in <module>()
     28 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import basic_session_run_hooks
     29 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import datasets
---> 30 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import estimators
     31 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import graph_actions
     32 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import learn_io as io

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/__init__.py in <module>()
    300 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators._sklearn import NotFittedError
    301 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.constants import ProblemType
--> 302 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.dnn import DNNClassifier
    303 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.dnn import DNNEstimator
    304 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.dnn import DNNRegressor

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py in <module>()
     33 from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers import optimizers
     34 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import metric_spec
---> 35 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import dnn_linear_combined
     36 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
     37 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import head as head_lib

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py in <module>()
     34 from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers import optimizers
     35 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import metric_spec
---> 36 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
     37 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import head as head_lib
     38 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import model_fn

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py in <module>()
     50 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import tensor_signature
     51 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators._sklearn import NotFittedError
---> 52 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io import data_feeder
     53 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.utils import export
     54 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.utils import saved_model_export_utils

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/__init__.py in <module>()
     24 from __future__ import print_function
     25 
---> 26 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import extract_dask_data
     27 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import extract_dask_labels
     28 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import HAS_DASK

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/dask_io.py in <module>()
     31 try:
     32   # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
---> 33   import dask.dataframe as dd
     34   allowed_classes = (dd.Series, dd.DataFrame)
     35   HAS_DASK = True

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import print_function, division, absolute_import
      2 
----> 3 from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,
      4                    repartition)
      5 from .io import (from_array, from_bcolz, from_array, from_bcolz,

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in <module>()
     34 no_default = '__no_default__'
     35 
---> 36 pd.computation.expressions.set_use_numexpr(False)
     37 
     38 

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'computation'
```

if i run the same command `import tensorflow as tf` again after this, for some reason it imports without any issues, but the imported tensorflow is not having a few modules available for example:

```
tf.contrib.layers
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-28c9425cf301> in <module>()
----> 1 tf.contrib.layers

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.pyc in __getattr__(self, item)
     51 
     52   def __getattr__(self, item):
---> 53     module = self._load()
     54     return getattr(module, item)
     55 

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.pyc in _load(self)
     40   def _load(self):
     41     # Import the target module and insert it into the parent's namespace
---> 42     module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
     43     self._parent_module_globals[self._local_name] = module
     44 

/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.pyc in import_module(name, package)
     35             level += 1
     36         name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
---> 37     __import__(name)
     38     return sys.modules[name]

/opt/ds/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py in <module>()
     23 
     24 # Add projects here, they will show up under tf.contrib.
---> 25 from tensorflow.contrib import batching
     26 from tensorflow.contrib import bayesflow
     27 from tensorflow.contrib import checkpoint

ImportError: cannot import name batching
```

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what happens when you do `tf.contrib.layers` right after the first (failed) import statement?

Comment: @FlyingTeller - updated the question